# \addfontfeatures combining issues

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I am trying to set up additional weights and widths for a variable font:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\blackseries}{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+axis={wght=900}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cond}{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+axis={wdth=50}}}}
```

However, I have two probably related issues.
If I set up `UprightFeatures` in

```
\setmainfont{NotoSans-VF.ttf}[
    Path                =   Fonts/Noto/variable-ttf/,
    UprightFont         =   *,
    UprightFeatures     =   {RawFeature={+axis={wght=400}}},
    ItalicFont          =   NotoSerif-Italic-VF.ttf,
    ItalicFeatures      =   {RawFeature={+axis={wght=400}}},
    BoldFont            =   *,
    BoldItalicFont      =   *,
    BoldFeatures        =   {RawFeature={+axis={wght=700}}},
    BoldItalicFeatures  =   {RawFeature={+axis={wght=700}}},
    Renderer            =   HarfBuzz,
]
```

then `\blackseries` don't work at all. If I comment it out, `\blackseries` works.

The second issue is that when I use `\blackseries\cond` it just compresses it, without making it bold.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{NotoSans-VF.ttf}[
    Path                =   Fonts/Noto/variable-ttf/,
    UprightFont         =   *,
    UprightFeatures     =   {RawFeature={+axis={wght=400}}},
    ItalicFont          =   NotoSerif-Italic-VF.ttf,
    ItalicFeatures      =   {RawFeature={+axis={wght=400}}},
    BoldFont            =   *,
    BoldItalicFont      =   *,
    BoldFeatures        =   {RawFeature={+axis={wght=700}}},
    BoldItalicFeatures  =   {RawFeature={+axis={wght=700}}},
    Renderer            =   HarfBuzz,
]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\blackseries}{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+axis={wght=900}}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cond}{\addfontfeature{RawFeature={+axis={wdth=50}}}}

\begin{document}
    
    \blackseries Text
    \cond condensed text
    
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two issues are rather independent from one another:

1. The first issue is that by explicitly specifying the RawFeature for an upright font, the "generic" RawFeature from `\addfontfeature` is overwritten. You could avoid that by setting `UprightFeatures={RawFeature={...}}` in `\addfontfeature` instead of `RawFeature={...}` directly, but of course that would only apply for upright fonts then... Of course in this case weight 400 is the default anyway, so it's easy to avoid the issue by just removing the explicit `UprightFeatures` and `ItalicFeatures`. If this were not the case, you could set `RawFeature={+axis={wght=400}}` directly in the `\setmainfont` argument to make it the default instead of setting it in `UprightFeatures` and `ItalicFeatures`. That avoids repetition and avoids overwriting less specific values later.
2. The other issue about combining these `\blackseries` and `\cond` is directly related to fontspec missing direct support for setting variable font axis values. Since you have to use `RawFeatures` the argument gets passed as is, so you end up with a font specifying two different `axis` features instead of one `axis` feature specifying two values. Generally the font handling always handles duplicate font features by letting the later one overwrite the first, so this doesn't have the intended effect. A future fontspec version will probably add a native syntax for setting this value which will avoid this.

For the time being, you have to specify the combinations manually. This can be done easily by using fontspec's `FontFace` feature to integrate the addition series values into LaTeX's NFSS which will then take care to handle combinations correctly. Here `black` is mapped to the NFSS equivalent `ub` (ultra bold) and `condensed` to `c`. Then you get something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% Attention, different font filenames. On my system the variable fonts don't have the -VF suffix, so you might want to add that back.
% Also I use the Sans version also for italic since I think that they fit better. Of course YMMV.
\setmainfont{NotoSans.ttf}[
    UprightFont         =   *,
    BoldFont            =   *,
    BoldFeatures        =   {Weight=700},
    FontFace            =   {ub}{n}{Font = *, RawFeature={+axis={wght=900}}},
    FontFace            =   {c}{n}{Font = *, RawFeature={+axis={wdth=50}}},
    FontFace            =   {bc}{n}{Font = *, RawFeature={+axis={wght=700,wdth=50}}},
    FontFace            =   {ubc}{n}{Font = *, RawFeature={+axis={wght=900,wdth=50}}},
    ItalicFont          =   NotoSans-Italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont      =   NotoSans-Italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFeatures  =   {Weight=700},
    FontFace            =   {ub}{it}{Font = NotoSans-Italic.ttf, RawFeature={+axis={wght=900}}},
    FontFace            =   {c}{it}{Font = NotoSans-Italic.ttf, RawFeature={+axis={wdth=50}}},
    FontFace            =   {bc}{it}{Font = NotoSans-Italic.ttf, RawFeature={+axis={wght=700,wdth=50}}},
    FontFace            =   {ubc}{it}{Font = NotoSans-Italic.ttf, RawFeature={+axis={wght=900,wdth=50}}},
    Renderer            =   HarfBuzz,
]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\blackseries}{\fontseries{ub}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cond}{\fontseries{c}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\blackseries Text
\cond condensed text
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you very much. But can you elaborate a bit on how do these features combine? Should FontFaces be named in a specific way?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman See [`texdoc fntguide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/fntguide.pdf) for the standard naming of LaTeX's font series axis. Then LaTeX uses a lookup table to combine these, see `ltfssaxes` in [`texdoc source2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) for details.

Comment: Okay, I see. Maybe there is an easy way to which axes raw features are activated now, and just add another axis?